# Qml live render model

Tags: c++, qt, qml, animated-gif, after-effects

Imagine that you want to add car model into your ui. So that when cars door open , your 2d or 3d model show that in animation . And when it closed , model will get back into its first state. 
My question is , how should i create such model? Is gif ok or should i create a 3d model with something like Ae or 3dmax?
And after that how can i implement the mechanism for such use(transitions between different states of model). I know about animations and transitions in qml but those are only for qml components .

Comment: See [Qt.3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html)

Comment: Check out the examples of Kuesa (https://github.com/KDAB/kuesa), there's one doing exactly that.